# Is it possible to assign a value to a pattern (--) in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I got a very typical problem here. I have a huge bunch of formulas in my excel sheet and most of them Display `#N/A` because the data is unavailable. So I replaced all the formulas with `=IFERROR(original formula,"--")`. Worked perfect. Now the real problem is I have to add the fields and the fields having the error are added resulting to the result "--" even though there are values in other fields.

Eg: `A1=10`, `B1=20`, `C1= --`,

```
D1 = iferror(A1+B1+C1,"--")
```

The result now will be `--` instead of `30`.

So I am wondering, is there any way that I can assign a value 0 to "--" temporarily using VBA or some other mean so that I can come up with a result of 30.

Please help.

Comment: use Sum(A1:C1) it will ignore the text and sum the numbers. Or if they are not contiguous then SUM(A1,B1,C1),

Comment: I lost my brain somewhere.. That worked @ScottCraner I was struggling with a1+b1.. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom [Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68) of `General;General;_(* "--"??_);@` or one of the Accounting formats (with no currency symbol) and change your [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to return **0**.